# Get an XML datatype from a .NET type?

Tags: .net, xml, types

I'm wondering if there is a library - in .NET or otherwise - that will convert .NET types (eg. `Integer`, `String`, etc.) into [XML datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-primitive-datatypes) (eg. `int`, `string`).  Note that I'm looking to convert *types*, not the content of variables.  For example:

```
var xmlType = Convert.ToXmlType(typeof(bool));
Assert.That(xmlType.ToString(), Is.EqualTo("boolean"));
```

I don't mind making a lookup table since I'm not dealing with too many types, but I thought it would be nice to reuse such a thing if it's already out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to create the mappings, however it is not a one-to-one mapping. Reducing this to one-to-one will have to be an implementation detail on your end:

```
var mapping = (from XmlTypeCode cc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(XmlTypeCode))
              let xt = XmlSchemaType.GetBuiltInSimpleType(cc)
              where xt != null
              group cc by xt.Datatype.ValueType into gg
              select new { Type = gg.Key, XmlTypeCodes = gg.ToArray() })
              .ToDictionary(m => m.Type, m => m.XmlTypeCodes);
```

Sample output:

```
System.Boolean => Boolean
System.Byte => UnsignedByte
System.Byte[] => HexBinary,Base64Binary
System.DateTime => DateTime,Time,Date,GYearMonth,GYear,GMonthDay,GDay,GMonth
System.Decimal => Decimal,Integer,NonPositiveInteger,NegativeInteger,NonNegative
Integer,PositiveInteger
...
```

---

A *decent* approach to solving the one-to-one problem would be to take the first entry in the code table which works for every type but `String`. This also may not work for *newer* BCL types, but likely should going forward. It would be a breaking change for MS to rearrange the `XmlTypeCode` enumeration, but that's not to say this is fool proof:

```
// same as above except the ToDictionary
.ToDictionary(
    m => m.Type,
    m => m.Type != typeof(string) ? m.XmlTypeCodes.First() : XmlTypeCode.String);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind!  And thank you also for the idea on getting to a one-to-one mapping; I don't mind hard-coding an exception for strings.

Answer (score 2):

I found a second aproach using the framework itselfe.

```
XmlTypeMapping getQualifiedNameForSystemType(Type systemType_in)
{
    SoapReflectionImporter sri = new SoapReflectionImporter();
    return sri.ImportTypeMapping(systemType_in);
}
```